# clear and comprehensible way to calculate the string [12:3]

Tags: python

I new on python.
I have this string "[12:3]" and i what to calculate the difference between these two numbers. 
Ex: 12 - 3 = 9

Of course I can do something (not very clear) like this:

```
num1 = []
num2 = []
s = '[12:3]'
dot = 0;

#find the ':' sign
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == ':' :
        dot = i
#left side
for i in range(dot):
    num1.append(s[i])
#right side
for i in range(len(s) - dot-1):
    num2.append(s[i+dot+1])
return str(int("".join(num1))-int("".join(num2))+1)
```

But i'm sure the is a more clear and comprehensible way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, without `re`

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in s.strip('[]').split(':')]
print numbers[0] - numbers[1]
```

prints

```
9
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to pick the numbers out of your string:

```
import re

s = '[12:3]'
numbers = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+',s)]
return numbers[0]-numbers[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.match(r'\[(\d+):(\d+)\]', '[12:3]')
>>> match.groups()
('12', '3')
>>> a = int(match.groups()[0])
>>> b = int(match.groups()[1])
>>> a - b
9
```

The regular expression there says "`match` starting at the beginning of the string, find `[`, then any number of digits `\d+` (and store them), then a `:`, then any number of digits `\d+` (and store them), and finally `]`". We then extract the stored digits using `.groups()` and do arithmetic on them.